# windows phone slow connection GPRS httpClient request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, null, dotnet-httpclient

i'm testing my app wp7 and i don't understand this error.

When I use the wifi everything works fine.

While when I turn off the wifi, use the data connection with a maximum speed equal to 2G, the string that I get from the server SOMETIMES is equal to NULL.

```
public void sentInfo()
{
    myuri= new Uri(myuri);
    //create connection to web
    ReadDataFromWeb(myuri, myuseragent);
}

async private void ReadDataFromWeb(Uri site, string userAgent)
{
    is_connected_to_internet();

    client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", userAgent);

    var response = await client.GetAsync(site);
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    client.Dispose();
     bool isJson = false;
        if (result != null)
            isJson = IsJson(result);

        if (!isJson)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
        }
    ....
}
```

I thought it was a server problem, I went to edit the php.ini file but nothing has changed.

Then I try to insert a different link instead of my default links, and I realized that it behaves the same way: sometimes reads the html content, sometimes it returns null.

I have tried several methods to make requests to the server (HttpClient and WebClient) but all with this result if the connection is slow.

The problem is that only this application, windows phone, it behaves in this way, while the iOS and Android app even if the connection is slow sooner or later return something other than null.

Comment: Is it because it runs over the timeout? If so, why won't you increase HttpClient timeout?

Comment: What is " is_connected_to_internet();" doing? I find that when testing on a physical device and I switch to a radio connection from wifi, it sometimes takes as long as 40 seconds to report the true connection status while it's running synchronously on the UI thread. This article might help http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Checking_the_Internet_connection_type_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: is_connected_to_internet() check if there is an internet connection. But it isn't the problem. I don't undersand why the variable result sometimes is equal to NULL